# recover /etc/apt/preferences.d

Tags: apt, etc

I’m new to Ubuntu but not so noob .. I learn fast and I have a dream to be a developer .. I break up with windows and jump into the world of Unix .

So what I did is that I had the *duplicate repository* in resources.list I did manage that and I still have the problem ..

I figure out that others resources.list exit in the `/etc/apt/prefernces.d/` folder so I removed the whole folder and now I can't use the apt-get it tells me

```
W: Unable to read /etc/apt/preferences.d/ - FileExists (2: No such file or directory)
```

I tried with the *devilscripts (hardy)* but I didn't get it.
So please if some one could upload the folder for me I’m stuck.

i get this message exactly when i'm trying to add-repository 
**IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/webupd8team-y-ppa-manager-saucy.list'**

thnks everyone the problem wasn't so complicated i just mkdir the directory and now everything is fine thnks

Comment: yes i did unfortunatly

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My `/etc/apt/preferences.d` directory contains nothing.So only creation of that directory will solve that problem,

```
sudo mkdir /etc/apt/preferences.d
```